# PHP - excel file download

Tags: php

I download files from server but excel or word files are corrupted after download. Pdfs, jpgs etc. are ok.

```
ob_clean();
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private",false);
header("Content-Type: ").$att->getType();
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . basename($att->getName()));  
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
readfile($path);
```

Content type for excel I have - application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet

Answer (score 2):

Just Change

```
header("Content-Type: ").$att->getType();
```

to

```
header("Content-Type: ".$att->getType());
```

You send file with null Content-Type...

Comment: you are right but I also tried header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream"); or header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");  or header("Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet") with same result

Answer (score 1):

For excel and word, try changing

```
header("Content-Type: ").$att->getType();
```

to

```
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
```

or, for excel

```
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
```

or, for word

```
header("Content-Type: application/msword");
```

Comment: No, I had that it before but It wasn't working

Comment: For png and zip, you should use Content-type: image/png and Content-Type: application/zip respectively but in case of problem (say in your case), please try octet-stream or Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel or application/msword (please try my revised answer)

Answer (score 0):

Problem was different... I've just had in my php file new line after ?>
Thank Amin and Ken for help

Comment: Nice to know that you have fixed the problem. Have a nice day.